# Preset object Id when pushing to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a SortedList to sort my items inside the RecyclerView.
So I need to compare them by some unique Id, and Firebase provides awesome generated keys for that.

To push new value to a database I need to run:

```
public void addAdvert(Advert advert, String userId) {
        String id = reference.child(NODE_USERS)
        .child(userId)
        .child(NODE_ITEMS)
        .push()
        .getKey()   //execute this to just get the id

        advert.setId(id);
        getCurrentItemNode().child(advert.getId()).setValue(advert);

}
```

now my Advert item in database is fully equiped with Id and node key.

But I' curious, can I just write something like

```
reference.child(NODE_USERS)
            .child(userId)
            .child(NODE_ITEMS).push().setValue(advert);
```

And achieve the same result: both key and ID are set in database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the key in the item, you'll either have to perform two write operations *or* first generate the key and then write it.

But why do you want to store the key in the item to begin with?

As a side note, this code:

```
    String id = reference.child(NODE_USERS)
    .child(userId)
    .child(NODE_ITEMS)
    .push()
    .getKey()
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
    String id = reference.push().getKey()
```

Firebase's push IDs are client-side generated, statistically guaranteed to be unique values. They're not dependent on the path and there is no round-trip to the database needed to determine these values.

See this blog post for more information: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Comment: Is this an error @puf? Seems that `String id = reference.child(NODE_USERS).getKey()` would return whatever `NODE_USERS` is; perhaps you meant `reference.push().getKey()`? Or perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: Yup, that was indeed a copy/paste/modified-the-wrong-part. Thanks for catching!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to store key in the item to make item unique when I will get it from database next time.

Comment: Storing a JSON object under a key, ensures that it's unique. Then also storing that key as a the value of a property in the same JSON object just confuses matters.

Comment: True. Haven't thought that I can skip the key thing. Trying it now.